# Наречие в тупик

Tags: морфология, части-речи, наречия

На какой вопрос отвечает наречие в тупик?

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте отметить его галочкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **Эта улица ведет (куда?) в тупик.** Прямое значение обстоятельственного существительного. ТУПИК, 1. Улица, не имеющая сквозного прохода, проезда.

2) **Этот путь ведет (куда?) в тупик.** Переносное значение.

3) **Вопрос поставил меня в тупик.** Поставить в тупик – устойчивое выражение со значением "приводить в крайнее затруднение, замешательство".

В этом случае некорректно говорить о том, на какой вопрос отвечает падежная форма, она рассматривается как единое сочетание с определенным значением.

Comment: Но в предложении надо подчеркнуть как обстоятельство? Но какое?

Comment: "В тупик" — наречие?

Comment: В тупик - обстоятельство места (куда?), но если слово входит в устойчивое сочетание, то лучше рассматривать его как единый член предложения (поставить в тупик - затруднить).

Comment: В тупик - обстоятельственное существительное (наречное выражение). Так называют все падежные формы, которые отвечают на обстоятельственный вопрос,  как наречия, но пишутся раздельно, как существительные.